# jqgrid not passing record id for edit delete

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid

I am trying to use the edit delete functions in jqgrid.

I can't seem to get it to pass the record id to my processing page
the edit is sending all values, but the delete only sends the jqgridrow id (id=jqg16).
Obviously I need the record id so I know which record to delete!
The record id column is id_mdt;
my column that holds the record id is set up as follows:

```
myGrid = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
    url:'data/stokistdata_s_json.php?q=3', 
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST", 
    rowNum:10, 
    rowList:[50,100,150,200,300,400,500,600], 
    pager: '#prowed2', 
    sortname: 'name_mdt', 
    viewrecords: true, 
    gridview:true,
    sortorder: "asc", 
    rowNum:50, 
    scroll: true, 
    editurl: "data/server.php", 
    caption:"Stockist's and Orchid days",
    colNames:[
        'Actions',
        'id', //record id column
        'Type', 
        'Name', 
        'Geo Address',
        'Display Address',
        'Telephone',
        'Email', 
        'website', 
        'lat', 
        'lng', 
        'flag', 
        'description', 
        'active'
    ], 
    colModel:[{
        name:'Actions',
        index:'Actions',
        width:100,
        sortable:false,
        search:false
    }, {//record id column
        name:'id_mdt',
        index:'id_mdt',
        width:15,
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        search:false,
        hidden: true, 
        editable: true, 
        editrules: { edithidden: false }, 
        hidedlg: true           
    }, {
        name:'id_etp',
        index:'id_etp', 
        width:90, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        formatter:'select',
        editoptions:{value:":All;1:Stockist;2:Orchid Day"},
        search:true,
        stype:'select',
        sopt: ['eq'],
        searchoptions:{value:":All;1:Stockist;2:Orchid Day"}
    }, {
        name:'Name_mdt',
        index:'Name_mdt',
        align:"left", 
        width:150,
        editable:true,
        search:true,
        stype:'text',
        sopt:['cn']
    }, {
        name:'geoaddr_mdt',
        index:'geoaddr_mdt',
        width:150, 
        align:"left",
        editable:true,
        search:false,
        edittype:"textarea", 
        editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
    }, {
        name:'displayaddr_mdt',
        index:'displayaddr_mdt', 
        width:150, 
        align:"left",
        editable:true,
        search:false,
        edittype:"textarea", 
        editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
    }, {
        name:'telephone_mdt',
        index:'telephone_mdt', 
        width:80,
        align:"left",
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'email_mdt',
        index:'email_mdt', 
        width:80, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'website_mdt',
        index:'website_mdt', 
        width:80, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'lat_mdt',
        index:'lat_mdt', 
        width:40, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    } , {
        name:'lng_mdt',
        index:'lng_mdt', 
        width:40, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false
    }, {
        name:'flag_mdt',
        index:'flag_mdt', 
        width:20, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        editoptions: {value:{'1':'Flagged','0':'No Flag'}},
        search:true,//
        stype:'select',
        searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Flagged','0':'No Flag'}}//{value:":Both;1:Flagged;0:No Flag"}
    }, {
        name:'description_mdt',
        index:'description_mdt', 
        width:150, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:false,
        editable:true,
        search:false,
        edittype:"textarea", 
        editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
    }, {
        name:'active_mdt',
        index:'active_mdt', 
        width:20, 
        align:"left",
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
        edittype:"select",
        editoptions: {value:{'1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}},
        search:true,//
        stype:'select',
        searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}} //{value:":Both;1:Active;0:Hidden"}
    }], search : {
         caption: "Search...",
         Find: "Find",
         Reset: "Reset",
         matchText: " match",
         rulesText: " rules"
   },

    gridComplete: function(){ 
        var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
        for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
            var cl = ids[i]; 
            be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
            fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
            gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
        } 
    }
}); 

jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2",
    {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true},
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500},
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500}    // Add options

); 
myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{defaultSearch:'cn',stringResult:true});
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try adding `key: true` in your colModel for the id field.

Comment: thanks that works, though it sends it as id not id_mdt, on the proceessing page i have multiple case statements for the edit delete and add depending on which oper is sent, is ther antway to change the passed value to id_mdt instead of id??

Comment: ahh its ok it sends it as id for edit as-well so not a problem

Comment: see the option prmNames here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options. p.s. if that answered your question please accept the answer. thanks.